# I got "the project couldn't be opened:access to the path is denied"

Tags: windows, permissions, uipath

I got This message"The project 'C:\Users\abrar\Documents\Uipath\BlankProcess2\project.json' could not be opened:Access to the path 'C:\Users\abrar.nuget\packages\uipath\10.0.7004.31775\build\UiPath\aahook.dll' is denied" when I open a new project on UIPATH, I have tried to change the permission but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a nuget caching issue. Try running Studio with elevated permissions first (Run as Administrator) to see if the issue persists - if not, close it and run it again, this time not in elevated mode.

If that does not work, just remove UiPath's packages entirely (`C:\Users\abrar\.nuget\packages\uipath` in your case), then run Studio again. Open your project, and UiPath will automatically restore all missing packages (you will need to be connected to the internet though).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to run it from a different Windows user account.

Answer (score 0):

*(Can't comment on question, so i'm writing as answer. Also, you may have solved the problem already, but if not or for someone that could have this issue it may help)*

It may be a typo, but seems like you're missing a backslash **\** between username and .nuget:

> 'C:\Users\**abrar\.nuget**\packages\uipath\10.0.7004.31775\build\UiPath\aahook.dll'

Also make sure that this folder and files exist, seems to be a package published from UiPath Studio.